# Why can't I connect to Cassandra on my MacOS?

Tags: python, database, cassandra, nosql

I am using MAC OS (Monterey 12.2.1) Apple M1, Chip

PostgreSQL works fine for me but Cassandra doesn't. After installing and importing cassandra, I tried connecting to the local instance of Apache Cassandra as done below

```
import cassandra    
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
try: 
   cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1']) 
   session = cluster.connect()
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

However I got the following error:

```
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I have `cassandra 4.0.3` installed and and I have tried many of the suggestions online but didn't work for me. I cannot even find files like `cassandra-env.sh`, `cassandra.yaml`

With the command `java -version`, I have:

```
java version "1.8.0_321"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_321-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.321-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: how are you running cassanda. docker or local install. Try docker based setup if it suits you always more reliable to work.

https://cassandra.apache.org/_/quickstart.html

Comment: It's a local installation. Not familiar with docker. I'll give it a try through the shared link

Comment: I tried installing the docker and followed the instruction in the link above. After running the command: `docker run --name cassandra cassandra`, the process got stucked at `INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-03-07 17:00:33,866 CassandraRoleManager.java:339 - Created default superuser role 'cassandra'` and couldn't continue anymore

Comment: That was alright. Unfortunately I can't teach you whole about docker there is lot of learn. I wrote a quick blog to make this work. Please have a look here.

https://indolent-dev.medium.com/running-cassandra-using-docker-in-apple-macbooks-with-m1-chip-9a9fb5604e94

Comment: Thanks this works for me. I was able to create a keyspace, populate and retrieve from it on my `terminal`. I was trying the above connection on VSCODE (notebook) but I still got same `unable to connect to any servers...` error.  Doing everything works well on terminal but starting the connection on notebook cell flags same error

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Time to learn docker :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's not abundantly clear *how* Cassandra was installed on your Mac (homebrew, etc).  But as another possible method of achieving this, I'll list out the steps about how *I* run Apache Cassandra on my Mac, and maybe that'll help you.

Download the tarball.  For this example, I'll go with Apache Cassandra 4.0.3.

https://dlcdn.apache.org/cassandra/4.0.3/apache-cassandra-4.0.3-bin.tar.gz

Move the tarball to the desired location:

```
mv ~/Downloads/apache-cassandra-4.0.3-bin.tar.gz ~/local/
```

Untar:

```
cd ~/local
tar -zxvf apache-cassandra-4.0.3-bin.tar.gz
cd apache-cassandra-4.0.3
```

Configure (if you skip this step, it *will*) start:

```
atom conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Start:

```
bin/cassandra -p cassandra.pid
```

This ^ starts Cassandra with a PID file.  That allows you to break-away from the output, and it will still keep running in the background (unlike `bin/cassandra` or `bin/cassandra -f`).

Comment: It works.I can now work with Cassandra on jupyter notebook in VSCODE. Just one more thing I observed. When I run the command: `bin/cassandra -p cassandra.pid`, It got stuck at `INFO  [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2022-03-08 21:31:01,740 LogTransaction.java:240 - Unfinished transaction log, deleting /Users/myusername/Downloads/apache-cassandra-4.0.3/data/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/nb_txn_flush_863b0330-9f05-11ec-96ef-452e901e4bb9.log 
INFO  [main] 2022-03-08 21:31:01,758 StorageService.java:2784 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1:7000 state jump to NORMAL`. Does this mean its running

Comment: Yes, @Craving_gold it's running.  It probably had an incomplete file due to a previous startup attempt.  When you see `state jump to NORMAL`, that means it's good!

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that there is no Cassandra instance running on `localhost` listening on port `9042`:

```
('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1:9042': \
  ConnectionRefusedError(61, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. \
  Last error: Connection refused")})
```

You need to confirm that Cassandra is running on your Mac. The quickest way is to determine if there is a process listening on port `9042` with either of these commands:

```
$ netstat -tnlp
```

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Cassandra by default listens for client connections on CQL port `9042` configured in `cassandra.yaml` with:

```
native_transport_port: 9042
```

Clients connect to Cassandra using the `rpc_address` in `cassandra.yaml`:

```
rpc_address: localhost
```

If you've set it to your Mac's IP address then you will need to use it as the contact point on this line of your app instead of `localhost`:

```
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
```

If you're new to Cassandra, I recommend having a look at [datastax.com/dev](https://www.datastax.com/dev) which has lots of free hands-on interactive learning resources. In particular, the [Cassandra Fundamentals](https://www.datastax.com/learn/cassandra-fundamentals) learning series lets you learn the basic concepts quickly. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks. I used the above command to check if a process is listening on port 9042 but found none running on it. Also, the native_transport_port in cassandra.yaml is 9042, the rpc_address is also localhost. Still not working for me

Comment: Then that means that Cassandra isn't running. Have a look at the `system.log` for clues. If you update your original question with the last full error message + full stacktrace, I'd be happy to look at it. Cheers!